# What's the easiest way to use glow/blur/wind effect on my scene?

Tags: webgl, three.js

I want to use glow/blur/wind effect on my models (or on my complete scene). How should I do this? What's the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get a better answer if you provided more concrete details of what you want to implement.

For a full screen pass:

Render scene as normal to off screen texture.
Bind texture containing rendered scene as input texture for next pass:

Render a full-screen quad (two triangles) with a simple vertex shader.
Inside fragment shader you do your blur/glow/whatever effect by sampling texture in interesting ways.

Note if you have any HUD elements you want to render these after the fullscreen effect.

Comment: I have animated collada models. I want to use the above mentioned effects on them. Or a full-screen quad soultion would be grat as well.
Yes, I played a lot with the fragment shader, but without results so far. Could you please give a fragment shader level blur code example?

Comment: For better results, Google "GLSL Blur" or "GLSL X" where X is the effect you want to implement.

Comment: Here is a link to a GLSL gaussian blur: http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/11/gaussian-blur-filter-shader/